# От простого к сложному

Tags: орфография

Следует ли обучать ребёнка написанию слов "йагода" и "йаблоко" до того, как обучать ребёнка написанию слов "ягода" и "яблоко"?

Примечание

Если бы буква "й" отображала обычный согласный речевой звук, тогда бы в русском языке было много слов, которые начинаются названой буквой (например: "йагода", "йаблоко", "йама", "йак").

Comment: Я бы на месте родителей вообще не трогала эту тему, предоставила бы учителю её объяснить,иначе есть опасность всё запутать. В младших классах сейчас хорошие развивающие методики, дети всё прекрасно понимают.

Comment: А я на Вашем месте вообще не вёлся бы на троллинг Галактиона со товарищи.

Comment: Когда  слова  начинаются  с  буквы  Й,  её  хочется  произнести  несколько  отдельно,  как  в  словах:  Йошкар-Ола,  Нью-Йорк,  йогурт.  Так  что  это  буквосочетание  не  равноценно  звуку,  который  наблюдается  в  словах   ёжик,  ёлка  и  т.п.

Comment: Гласные в других языках тоже произносятся по-разному в зависимости от своей позиции в словах, для этого и предусмотрена словарная транскрипция. Ну чем русские гласные хуже??))) Мы-то их чтение прекрасно знаем, а иностранцы - пожалуйте учить, как мы сами заучиваем англо/франко/немецкую премудрость...

Answer (score 2):

Действительно, мягкий вариант гласного, следующего  после мягкого согласного,  мы можем условно изобразить как (краткий И)+А, который мало чем отличается от (Й)+А.

(И – это  гласный верхнего подъема, который по артикуляции напоминает звук Й, но при этом   звук И состоит только из голоса, а звук Й  включает небольшое количество шума).

Можно сравнить: лёд - (л(и)о т)и льёт (л (й) о т). Таким образом, ДВОЙНАЯ работа йотированных гласных Я, Ё, Ю, Е очень похожа на два варианта ОДНОЙ И ТОЙ ЖЕ работы.

Но вот в школьных (да и не в школьных) учебниках об этом не говорят, предпочитая рассуждения о двойной роли йотированных гласных, да и о мягких вариациях А, О, У  как-то не упоминают.

Comment: Немного о "мягких" гласных. АКУСТИЧЕСКИ они отличаются  от обычных (твердых) гласных, и это видно на спектрографе - слитное произношение не может не сказаться на качестве гласного. Согласно ФОНОЛОГИЧЕСКОЙ терминологии, мы имеем доминанту (основной гласный звук) и его мягкую вариацию. Что касается детей, то не исключено, что они ЕЩЕ ЛУЧШЕ БЫ ПОНИМАЛИ, если бы им сказали следующее: в паре ЛА-ЛЯ буква А обозначает твердую пару, а буква Я - мягкую пару. Да и при обучении чтению это обязательно учитывается.

Comment: 1. Я могу воспроизвести "мягкий" гласный звук, который есть в словах "ляля", "тятя", "дядя", ...

2. По моему мнению, детское "а" (например, в предложении "Уря!") пронзительнее, чем взрослое "а" (например, в предложении "Ура!").

Comment: А  почему  вам  кажется,  что  дети  говорят  "уря" ?